# Kotlin + SpringBoot 2.0.0-M4 failed tu load application context (BeanCreationException)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, mockito, kotlin

I'm working with Kotlin and Spring (through SpringBoot).
I was on 2.0.0-M3 and everything was right.

I decided to jump to M4. Then, I got some troubles.

I got the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:107)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:242)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getJavaConstructor, parameter $receiver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:740)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:138)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getJavaConstructor, parameter $receiver
    at kotlin.reflect.jvm.ReflectJvmMapping.getJavaConstructor(ReflectJvmMapping.kt)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.lambda$discover$2(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:169)
    at java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:267)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer$Discoverers$2.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:165)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.discover(PreferredConstructorDiscoverer.java:77)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.<init>(BasicPersistentEntity.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaPersistentEntityImpl.<init>(JpaPersistentEntityImpl.java:54)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:66)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.mapping.JpaMetamodelMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(JpaMetamodelMappingContext.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:376)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:343)
    at java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.initialize(AbstractMappingContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:90)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.createInstance(JpaMetamodelMappingContextFactoryBean.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.AbstractFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractFactoryBean.java:141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
    ... 40 more
```

Here is my code:

Entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "code_list")
class CodeList : Serializable {
    /* ----- FIELDS ----- */
    //endregion


    //region GET / SET methods
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NO_SECSOC", nullable = false)
    var secSocId: Long? = null
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_CODE_LIST")
    var codelistId: String? = null
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NO_COM_PARITAIRE")
    var comParitaireId: String? = null
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NO_EMPLOYEUR")
    var employerId: Long? = null
    @Id
    @Column(name = "NO_CCTE")
    var ccteId: String? = null
    @Id
    @Column(name = "VAL_NUM")
    var numberValue: Long? = null
    @Id
    @Column(name = "VAL_STRING")
    var stringValue: String? = null

    @Column(name = "DT_DEBUT_EFFET")
    var startEffectDate: LocalDate? = null

    @Column(name = "DT_FIN_EFFET")
    var endEffectDate: LocalDate? = null

    @Embedded
    var label: MultilingualString? = null

    /** Set the type of value to use  */
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CODE_LIST", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    var codeListType: CodeListType? = null

    //region Constructor
    constructor() {}

    constructor(secSocId: Long?, employerId: Long?, ccteId: String, codeListId: String) {
        this.secSocId = secSocId
        this.employerId = employerId
        this.ccteId = ccteId
        this.codelistId = codeListId
    }
    //endregion

}
```

Repository

```
@Component
class CodeListRepository {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var entityManager: EntityManager

    fun findCodeListLikeCB(predicateMap: Map<String, Any?>): List<CodeList> {

        val cb = entityManager.criteriaBuilder

        val query = cb.createQuery(CodeList::class.java)

        val codeListRoot = query.from(CodeList::class.java)

        val predicateList: ArrayList<Predicate> = ArrayList()

        // foreach to build predicateList
        for ((key, value) in predicateMap) {
            if (value != null) {
                // For a list, needed to add a condition IN
                if (value is List<*>)
                    predicateList.add(codeListRoot.get<Any>(key).`in`(value))

                //For a date, needed to add condition
                //  For start date --> before param start date
                //  For end date   --> after param date or null
                if (value is LocalDate) {
                    if (key == "startEffectDate") {
                        predicateList.add(cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(codeListRoot.get("startEffectDate"), value))
                    }
                    if (key == "endEffectDate") {
                        // cb.conjunction allow to add parenthesis to the predicate
                        val predicate = cb.conjunction()
                        predicate.expressions.add(cb.or(cb.greaterThan(codeListRoot.get("endEffectDate"), value), cb.isNull(codeListRoot.get<Any>("endEffectDate"))))
                        predicateList.add(predicate)
                    }
                }
                if (value !is LocalDate && value !is List<*>) {
                    predicateList.add(cb.equal(codeListRoot.get<Any>(key), value))
                }
            }
        }

        query.select(codeListRoot).where(cb.and(*predicateList.toTypedArray()))

        return entityManager.createQuery(query).resultList
    }

}
```

Test class

```
@ComponentScan("be.groups")
@EntityScan("be.groups")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = arrayOf("be.groups"))
@SpringBootTest(classes = arrayOf(DatabaseComponent::class))
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class CodeListRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var repository: CodeListRepository

    @Test
    fun findCodeListLikeCB() {
        val codeLists = repository.findCodeListLikeCB(mapOf("codelistId" to "CANAL"))
        assertNotNull(codeLists)
        assertFalse(codeLists.isEmpty())

        val codeList = repository.findCodeListLikeCB(mapOf("codelistId" to "CANAL", "numberValue" to 0))
        assertNotNull(codeList)
        assertFalse(codeList.isEmpty())
        assertEquals(codeList.size, 1)
        assertEquals(codeList[0].codelistId, "CANAL")
        assertEquals(codeList[0].numberValue, 0)
    }

}
```

Test configuration (mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker)

```
mock-maker-inline
```

Any idea on what went wrong since 2.0.0-M3 ?

Comment: Thanks I am going to have a look.

Comment: I have created a repro project from this StackOverflow question and indeed such exception is raised, but the stacktrace seems to be at Spring Data Commons level which calls directly Kotlin API, so I have moved this issue to https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACMNS-1170, it will be handled by Spring Data team.

Comment: Hello @SébastienDeleuze !  thanks for the commitment, I really appricate !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been fixed since 2.0.0-M5

Answer (score 0):

have same problem.
remove all constructor of Entity class except default no-arg constructor. that solve problem

Comment: Thx. That's a solution but even we may not need constructors it that case, it's not sur that you'll never need it in the future. I'll wait few days before validate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could find useful kotlin compiler plugins. For this case (or similar) I recommend to use [jpa compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support). It would generate behind the scenes default no-args constructor for classes annotated with  @Entity, @Embeddable and @MappedSuperclass automatically, which would allow kotlin reflection api to correctly create and populate for example entities without a need to provide every single field as optional.

Answer (score 0):

I added kotlin-reflect dependency and this worked for me.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```